# Server command-line automation (updating the project)

Tags: linux, windows, command-line, ssh, automation

How can I automate running some commands on remote server?

For example I use windows machine. I run bat-file.

- it compiles resources (js + css)
- commits code to SVN
- connects to server by ssh
- updates from SVN on that server (using my SVN password stored on windows)
- runs some sh-scripts
- restarts daemons

How can I automate remote tasks? (last 3 of them are run on remote server)

Comment: This is best answered on superuser

Comment: I think that there are a lot of developers who automated such kind of processes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need to do is create a bash script on the server to do this.  Simply create a file, copy in each command that you run (1 command per line) and save the file.  Then when you connect to the remote server you can simply run

```
sh /path/to/mybashfile
```

and it will run all of those commands.  If you were running openssh client from the command line you could simply do

```
ssh user@server "sh /path/to/mybashfile"
```

but I'm not sure what client you're using on windows.  I'm pretty sure you can do something similar with putty.

If you wanted to automate this even more, you could create a bash script which would check the newest revision of the repository and if it's newer than the currently installed revision, run those commands.  Then you could create a cron job to run that bash script once ever N minutes.

Answer (score 2):

What you mean automate? Like running on a daily basis? 
For that you schedule them.
So for the 2 first items you can do it by batch file as you mention. And if you have a php server running on the remote server you can there create a php script that will execute the last 3 items.
For this you can have a page like hxxp://myserver.com/update.php (or hxxp://myserver.com/update.php?password=12345678 to avoid someone else to execute it) the your batch file in windows would do something like:

- compiles resources (js + css)
- commits code to SVN
- make a request to the url hxxp://myserver.com/update.php that will execute the remaing items on the server side

Using php you can execute .sh command using exec('.sh file').

Hope this helps and i can get you the php scripts if you have trouble.

C

Comment: Not daily, only when it's needed. The problem is server script should use SVN without stored password. So client should give login/password to server(POST, to avoid logs), and server script should use something like pipes to give password to SVN.